# Can we create image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, image.createimage

i searched so much but last time i want to confirm that can we create an image using jQuery or any other client side scripting? if yes please provide me a link for that documentation.

Comment: `var image = $("<img/>",{"src":"somepath", "alt" : "image"})` <-- are u looking for this? or did i mis read the question?

Comment: what do you mean by "creating image" ?? do you want to create the img src dynamically or something else? give a briefing about what you have tried so far.

Comment: @hungerpain i want to generate new image using text like we create in php using @imagecreate().

Comment: @Razor i want to create/ generate image not src.

Comment: using HTML5 yes(using canvas)..but not directly from jquery or javascript

Comment: @Jay something like this ? http://javascript.mfields.org/2011/creating-an-image-in-javascript/